# Qt/MinGW compiling error: no type named 'type' in 'struct std::enable_if<false, std::basic_ostream<char>&>'

Tags: c++, qt, gcc, mingw, ostream

I'm trying to compile a software by using Qt 5.12.10 with MinGW 7.3.0 64bit on Windows 10 64bit with multiple dependencies, after solving many errors of dependency directories i came to an error which i can't overcome until now. The gtest dependency seems to include ostream at which my Qt Creator stops with the following error message:

`error: no type named 'type' in 'struct std::enable_if<false, std::basic_ostream<char>&>'`

So i opened the file which is located in the MinGW folder and found the following codeblock which seems to be the problem:

```
#if __cplusplus >= 201103L
  template<typename _Ch, typename _Up>
    basic_ostream<_Ch, _Up>&
    __is_convertible_to_basic_ostream_test(basic_ostream<_Ch, _Up>*);

  template<typename _Tp, typename = void>
    struct __is_convertible_to_basic_ostream_impl
    {
      using __ostream_type = void;
    };

  template<typename _Tp>
    using __do_is_convertible_to_basic_ostream_impl =
    decltype(__is_convertible_to_basic_ostream_test
             (declval<typename remove_reference<_Tp>::type*>()));

  template<typename _Tp>
    struct __is_convertible_to_basic_ostream_impl
    <_Tp,
     __void_t<__do_is_convertible_to_basic_ostream_impl<_Tp>>>
    {
     using __ostream_type =
        __do_is_convertible_to_basic_ostream_impl<_Tp>;
    };

  template<typename _Tp>
    struct __is_convertible_to_basic_ostream
    : __is_convertible_to_basic_ostream_impl<_Tp>
    {

    public:
      using type = __not_<is_void<
        typename __is_convertible_to_basic_ostream_impl<_Tp>::__ostream_type>>;
      constexpr static bool value = type::value;
    };

  template<typename _Ostream, typename _Tp, typename = void>
    struct __is_insertable : false_type {};

  template<typename _Ostream, typename _Tp>
    struct __is_insertable<_Ostream, _Tp,
                          __void_t<decltype(declval<_Ostream&>()
                                           << declval<const _Tp&>())>>
                                   : true_type {};

  template<typename _Ostream>
    using __rvalue_ostream_type =
      typename __is_convertible_to_basic_ostream<
        _Ostream>::__ostream_type;

  /**
   *  @brief  Generic inserter for rvalue stream
   *  @param  __os  An input stream.
   *  @param  __x  A reference to the object being inserted.
   *  @return  os
   *
   *  This is just a forwarding function to allow insertion to
   *  rvalue streams since they won't bind to the inserter functions
   *  that take an lvalue reference.
  */

  template<typename _Ostream, typename _Tp>
    inline
    typename enable_if<__and_<__not_<is_lvalue_reference<_Ostream>>,
                             __is_convertible_to_basic_ostream<_Ostream>,
                             __is_insertable<
                               __rvalue_ostream_type<_Ostream>,
                               const _Tp&>>::value,
                      __rvalue_ostream_type<_Ostream>>::type
    operator<<(_Ostream&& __os, const _Tp& __x)
    {
      __rvalue_ostream_type<_Ostream> __ret_os = __os;
      __ret_os << __x;
      return __ret_os;
    }

#endif // C++11
```

Especially this part seems to produce the error:

```
    inline
    typename enable_if<__and_<__not_<is_lvalue_reference<_Ostream>>,
                             __is_convertible_to_basic_ostream<_Ostream>,
                             __is_insertable<
                               __rvalue_ostream_type<_Ostream>,
                               const _Tp&>>::value,
                      __rvalue_ostream_type<_Ostream>>::type
    operator<<(_Ostream&& __os, const _Tp& __x)
    {
      __rvalue_ostream_type<_Ostream> __ret_os = __os;
      __ret_os << __x;
      return __ret_os;
    }
```

After some internet search i found that maybe something is wrong  with the operator definition caused by the **enable_if**. But the code is not written by me and is part of the MinGW files, so i don't understand how to fix it. Can someone help?

Comment: Which c++ standard are you using in the compiler? e.g. In the project file there's something like CONFIG+=c++17 (assuming you are using qmake)

Comment: Sorry for the late response, i didn't found something like that in the project file. But there was a "global.pri" file in which i found CONFIG+=c++17. And yes, i'am using qmake.

Comment: Well, that's an include file for qmake project pro file, where you should find something like `include(global.pri)`. However I would check all the build options, Have you googled something like "mingw std library build error"?